# SKAction does not work with overlaySKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am familiar with running SKActions and never experienced problems with it.

But here is the problem, my main game is in ARKit with SceneKit and I am adding a SpriteKit overlay on top to display some HUD :

```
sceneView.overlaySKScene = scene
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFit
```

The 2D HUD displays correctly and I can move positions, rotations, scales by code but I am unable to run any animation (even when creating nodes from code and adding them as child):

```
class OverlaySKScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        someSprite = childNode(withName: "someSprite") as! SKSpriteNode
        someSprite.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi, duration: 1.0))     
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same problem for my SpriteKit HUD in SceneKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1519654-ispaused), SKScene.isPaused should be set to false:

> If the value is true, the scene’s content is fixed onscreen. No actions are executed and no physics simulation is performed.
>   When an application moves from an active to an inactive state, isPaused is automatically set to true. When an application returns to an active state, isPaused is automatically set to its previous value.

That kinda explains why it ran the actions if your pause/unpause the scene in Xcode...that "active state" changes.

So after you set your overlaySKScene, you must remember to set it's *isPaused* property to false. That gets actions running but now the issues just got very strange. I have a basic SKSpriteNode declared in my Scene.swift as frigidityBar. Typical setup with a SKSpriteNode named "frigidityBar" in Scene.sks.

```
 var frigidityBar: SKSpriteNode!
```

Running an action on it like this does not work:

```
    frigidityBar!.run(SKAction.colorize(with: SKColor.orange, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1.0)) {
        print("Colorize action did run!")
    }
```

but this does.

```
    displayNode.childNode(withName: "frigidityBar").run(SKAction.colorize(with: SKColor.orange, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1.0)) {
        print("Colorize action did run!")
    }
```

As does this:

```
    (frigidityBar as SKNode).run(SKAction.colorize(with: SKColor.orange, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1.0)) {
        print("Colorize action did run!")
    }
```

Even casting as an outright SKSpriteNode fails:

```
  (frigidityBar as SKSpriteNode).run(SKAction.colorize(with: SKColor.orange, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1.0)) {
        print("Colorize action did run!")
    }
```

I'm not expecting any silver bullets here but any ideas, hunches or guesses are welcomed.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much it worked !
I don't even have to do the cast workaround, someSprite = childNode(withName: "someSprite") as! SKSpriteNode; fetches the correct reference on didMove callback. Maybe you are either not fetching the reference on the overlay SKScene or your issue is specific to the colorize action, or to nodes added after the didMove callback occurs ?

Answer (score 1):

Im having the same issue if anyone else has an answer it would be gladly welcomed.

I notice that if I pause the app in Xcode and then continue it the actions run as expected.

Comment: I also tried running the actions inside DispatchQueue.main.async just in case with no results.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. Only when I pause before the SKAction and then resume, it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the culprit was SCNView’s `.isPlaying` property that was set to `false` (the default, according to the docs. Ouch!).

Once I explicitly set it to `true`, all SpriteKit actions on my overlay scene began to work.

*(The accpeted answer mentioning SKScene’s `.isPaused`, and confirming it wasn’t the case in my code, led me to look further into SCNView for a similar flag...)*

I **really** hope my wasting half a day banging my head against the wall helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Is your setup code called? I don't think `-didMoveToView:` is called in the case of an overlay scene (what would its `SKView` argument be?)

The same code can *probably* be moved to the place where the overlay scene is set.

Comment: Yes the setup code is called, the argument looks like an ARCL.SceneLocationView instance ... <ARCL.SceneLocationView: 0x11650b3d0 | session=0x116513540 scene=<SCNScene: 0x1c0136e40> sceneTime=0.000000 frame={{0, 0}, {768, 975}} pointOfView=<SCNNode: 0x1c45e5400 | camera=<SCNCamera: 0x11440c270> | no child>>. I inspected the superclasses, got ARSCNView, which is an SCNView which is an UIView.